# How to use external javascript and CSS library in Angular13 project

Tags: angular

I have just used Angular 13 and I want to use my external CSS and javascript library but I tried all the way, like => write path and active that in the angular.json but it doesn't work for me.
I just want to know what should I do to use my libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the best way to include styles in multi-components.
In your component, you just need to change the `styleUrls` to what you want...
for example, I have a `style.css` file in my assets folder...

So I want to use `style.css` in my `app.component`, So I change the  `styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']` value like this `styleUrls: ['../assets/Css/style.css']`.

**Note: `..` make your position file to downer E.g: your component in `src/app/home/home.component.cs` and you want to connect with your assets file so you need to use the file path like this `../../assets/Css/style.css`**.

If you active your style.css (which you want to use in one of your components) in *angular.json*, the style.css active for all your components and make their style change!

Answer (score 0):

Angularish way to add js and external files would be to include them in `angular.json`

```js
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/android-chrome-192x192.png",
              "src/android-chrome-256x256.png",
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/theme.scss",
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/cuber/src/scripts/vendor/threejs/src/Three.js"
```

If you then afterwards, for example, would like to use a function from one of those external files - you would first need to declare it, and use them in component like so:

```js
declare const myTest: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  onClick() {
    myTest();
  }
}
```

Another not so Angularish way would be to use `<script>` tags in `index.html`

Comment: Should I include them in "assets" or "styles" and "scripts"?
Another question is when we use them in our component, where does that declare know which CSS or javascript I want to use?

Comment: Incase my example above was not clear enough. Everything ending with .js go in scripts. everything ending in .css go in styles, rest can go into assets.

Comment: Whenever I don't think it's necessary to use (declare const myTest: any;) in the component because I didn't use that in my component and that works for me.

Comment: `declare const myTest: any;` would be how to import and function from an external .js file to you angular file and how to use it. But as far as the original question is concerned yes, for just importing the files, declaring a function from those is not necessary. I will explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a file from a third-party package you have installed using `npm` (or `yarn`) you can use a few ways. The most angularish is using `angular.json` file in the root folder of your Angular project.

For instance I want to use lightGallery in my project. I install it with `npm install lightgallery --save` and then add its stylesheet in my `angular.json` file:

```
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/visitor-frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/lightgallery/scss/lightgallery.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

The path base of all relative paths in this files is the root folder of your project, the very folder the file `angular.json` is placed in.

Notice the string `"node_modules/lightgallery/scss/lightgallery.scss"`. `npm` installs packages into `node_modules` folder. If you want to import a file from this folder you just need to find required file in the `node_modules` folder and reference it in the corresponding array: `styles` or `scripts`. So if you want to import `lightgallery.es5.js` from the same package you need to change `angular.json` like this:

```
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/visitor-frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/lightgallery/scss/lightgallery.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/lightgallery/lightgallery.es5.js"
            ]
          },
```

You can find more on the topic here: [Usage of Angular libraries published to npm](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#using-runtime-global-libraries-inside-your-app)